# "Flashing" image in Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am using Vue.js to make a hybrid moblie application. I am currently using quasar framework. I added an image in the application; using `<img />` tag. I used:

```
img.logo {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

to make it responsive. For some reason when the route is changed or at the start of the application, this image "flashes". By flashes I mean: it appears as a full sized image that covers the whole screen for a split second and then goes back to `max-width: 100%;`. What can I do to prevent that?

Comment: It seems that your styles are been loaded with a bit of delay. Can you use javascript? If yes, I would recommend hiding all the app's content until all images are loaded. Then, unhide the page content.

Comment: Could you show us your html header?

Comment: quick fix would be to inline the width: `<img src="..." style="max-width: 100%;">`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your CSS is being loaded after your JavaScript, depending of the size of your CSS and the event which trigger the style to change you could experience some minor delay.

You could try to load your CSS in the header before your actual JavaScript and use Chrome Network tools to see if you have any bottleneck when loading your CSS.

Further tips to optimize your CSS delivery are:

- Minimize HTTP Requests, use CSS concatenation.
- Enable compression, consider gzip.
- Minificate your CSS, to reduce CSS file size.
- Enable browser caching.
- Optimize Images and SVG.